# Error while sending string and Latlng from one activity to another

Tags: android

I want to some variables from one activity to another but my application got crashed
My log:

```
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.restaurantfinder/com.example.restaurantfinder.RestaurantInfo}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:260)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3680)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at com.example.restaurantfinder.RestaurantInfo.onCreate(RestaurantInfo.java:49)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
10-24 17:31:05.765 E/AndroidRuntime(16529): ... 11 more
```

and this is my code

```
  view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(context,RestaurantInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", restaurantDetailList.get(position).getRestaurantName());
                Bundle args=new Bundle();
                args.putParcelable("geopiont", restaurantDetailList.get(position).getGeoPiont());
                intent.putExtra("bundle", args);
                intent.putExtra("address", restaurantDetailList.get(position).getAddress());
                intent.putExtra("type", restaurantDetailList.get(position).getType());
                intent.putExtra("flag",(restaurantDetailList.get(position).getFlag()));
                context.startActivity(intent);

                }
        });
        return view;
```

Comment: Put the line `RestaurantInfo.java:49`

Comment: Can you post the code where you want to get the extras form the intent in your started activity? May you are trying to "get" the wrong key.

Answer (score 1):

you must be setting lat long to a textview...Please Convert your latlng to String and then after set it to textview as like below;

```
yourtextview.setText(latlng+"");
```

or

```
yourtextview.setText(String.ValueOf(latlng));
```

Hope it will help.